# iPhone UI: No edit button for UITableView, bad idea?

Tags: iphone, user-interface, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController which lets the user drill down into different records.  On the second level/view, the user can add and edit new records.  But, I am not sure what to do, since the back button is on the top left, and I need to put the "Add" button on the top right, so there is no room (keeping to HIG) for the edit button, which would normally go where the back button is. (I am using a tab bar, so can't put it at the bottom.)

Do you think that it is logical, to expect users to know to swipe to delete a record?  Or, do I need to have an edit button?  If I DO need an edit button, where should I put it if I am following HIG?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swipe to delete is a firmly established iphone UI interaction, so yes I would be comfortable expecting users to know that.  We've run into the same problem a few times, and yeah you only get two nav bar buttons so you've got to make a choice.  If you're already using the bottom for a tab bar, I don't see many other options.

Comment: I came across this while searching a related topic and thought I would mention that there are many ways to get more than 2 buttons in the navigation bar.  Though I still agree that you can rely on user's knowing of swipe to delete.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar situation in my app.

When the user taps the edit button I show an extra table cell at the end of my table which lets them add a new record. Not sure if that's feasible in your case.

Maybe add it at the beginning, or insert a button just above the UITableView? You could then also label the button "Add/Edit" to make it clear that that's how they can add new records, although I haven't done that.

Another option would be to have that extra button or table cell always visible.